# Using dotnet dev-certs with aspnet docker image

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

You can use `dotnet dev-certs https` to generate a self-signed certificate for use with ASP.NET as this dockerfile demontrates

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as build
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet new webapi -o app
RUN dotnet dev-certs https
RUN dotnet publish -o out app/app.csproj
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://*:443;http://*:80"
WORKDIR /app
RUN cp -r /src/out/* .
CMD ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

I would like to base my final image on the aspnet image though. So I change it to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as build
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet new webapi -o app
RUN dotnet dev-certs https
RUN dotnet publish -o out app/app.csproj

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 as final
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://*:443;http://*:80"
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /src/out .
CMD ["dotnet", "app.dll"]
```

I can build that, but when I run it, it fails because it can't find the certificate. I can't run `dotnet dev-certs https` in the final image, because the dev-certs command is only part of the SDK and not the aspnet image. I'd like to copy over the certificate to the final image, but I don't know where `dotnet dev-certs https` stores it and I can't find any documentation about it.

How do I solve this, so my image is based on aspnet and can accept requests over https?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After poking around, I found the certificate in /root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my/

Adding

```
COPY --from=build /root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my/* /root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my/
```

to the final image solved the issue.

Comment: This works because there are two different container images being used; one based on the SDK for the build and another based on just the .NET runtime for the final deployable image. They can't see each other's changes, so you need to copy from one to the other :)

Comment: You can set the certificate path by running `dotnet dev-certs https -ep [PATH/FILE_NAME.pfx] -p [PASSWORD]`  then you just had to copy it from SDK to apsnet image

Comment: The PFX should include the private key right? I'm basically trying your work around, but its complaining that the private key is not present: `The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key`

Comment: This works for me on MacOS, but not Ubuntu\Linux :\

Answer (score 6):

My requirement was to run the final container in docker compose environment.

Best accepted answer forward me to right direction, however I found some more steps have to be done. So posting here complete solution.

```
### Dockerfile exctract:

# in the build stage we generate the cert
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG PASSWORD_ENV_SEEDED

#generate the cert, define the path to store it and password to use
RUN dotnet dev-certs https -ep /https/aspnetapp.pfx -p ${PASSWORD_ENV_SEEDED}

#then in final stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS final
COPY --chmod=0755 --from=build /https/* /https/
```

`PASSWORD_ENV_SEEDED` - some password which will be seeded as environment variable

Next we need to tell asp.net to search for the cert, so defining 2 more environment variables:

`ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password`
`ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path`

```
### docker-compose.yaml

my-service:
  build:
    # in my case, Dockerfile was in a subfolder
    context: config-service
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    args:
      - PASSWORD_ENV_SEEDED=${PASSWORD_ENV_SEEDED}
  restart: unless-stopped
  ports:
    - 15005:443
  environment:
    - PASSWORD_ENV_SEEDED=some.long.password.fllkwefiwejf23049uwlekjf.sEFWEFGR98^&$
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=${PASSWORD_ENV_SEEDED}
    - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+:5000
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The steps in docker compose really what helped. I just needed 443 to run in docker behind a proxy that already had proper certs.. but oauth requests were comming from http on the server confusing itself. This worked a charm