# .NET Docker container cannot find dev certs

Tags: asp.net, docker

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET docker container, but keep getting the error below when starting the container:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:7.0-alpine3.16 AS base

RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine AS build
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN apk add --no-cache curl

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProject.WebApi/MyProject.WebApi.csproj", "MyProject.WebApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.WebApi/MyProject.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProject.WebApi"

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -r linux-musl-x64 -o out
RUN dotnet dev-certs https

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /src/MyProject.WebApi/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./MyProject.WebApi"]
```

As you can see I am installing the dev certs with `RUN dotnet dev-certs https` and as far as I understand these are installed on a different image than the actual image that is ran, but the files, including the certificates, are copied over to the correct image with `COPY --from=publish /src/MyProject.WebApi/out ./`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using dotnet dev-certs with aspnet docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69282468/using-dotnet-dev-certs-with-aspnet-docker-image)

Comment: Not really. I have inspected the files in the image and cannot find the certificates in the file path mentioned in that post. In addition I have a COPY step in my Dockerfile that should have copied the certificates to the correct location if they existed.

Comment: If you say so. I can't see where you'd copy the certificate though.

Comment: You either have to copy the certs from publish to build (which you do not seem to do) or mount a volume where the certs are located to your container at runtime.

Comment: I thought this line: `COPY --from=publish /src/MyProject.WebApi/out ./` was what was needed to copy the certs from publish to final which is the image that is actually run? Do you have a code example of where I need to put my COPY or mount step?

Comment: Also I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm running this from a docker-compose file.

Comment: The certs are not put into the project directory. They are put in below the home-directory of the user. The question @HansKilian has linked above has all the information needed. If you are not happy with where the certs are put by default, you can specify a path by passing arguemnt `-ep <path>` to `dotnet dev-certs https`

Comment: Ok I got it working using the post that @HansKilian linked, however I'm wondering if this is appropriate for production use? We are using this same Dockerfile for both local development and production and it seems like this from this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-7.0, that copying certificates is not recommended for production.

Comment: It is called *dev*-certs. They are simple self-signed certificates to get you going. In no case should they be used in production. When you use the same Dockerfile also for production, why do you create develeopment certs in your Dockerfile?

Comment: The Dockerfile in use for production does currently not have the dev-certs step and right now we are not using the Dockerfile for local development, but the plan is to do that. But when running locally I get the certificate error. Does this mean I actually need two different Dockerfiles, one for local development and one for production?

Comment: No, you do not need two Dockerfiles, you could just do it in the way described in the link you gave two comments above. I.e. create the dev-certs on your local machine and mount them into your container. But that is a completely different topic. Here you have asked, why the dev-certs you have created in your container cannot be found.