# C# API in Docker: Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, docker, visual-studio, https

I am trying to run a .NET project using docker-compose (from Visual Studio), and the DB image is created successfully, but the app itself is failing with the following message in Docker logs:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to
> configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the
> default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

It says the app is "Exited", doesn't even open the browser, and I can't start it manually.

I have tried to delete and create new dev certificates

```
dotnet dev-certs https --clean
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

delete *localhost* from *chrome://net-internals/#hsts*, restart Docker, Visual Studio, reinstall everything and nothing helped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using dotnet dev-certs with aspnet docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69282468/using-dotnet-dev-certs-with-aspnet-docker-image)